# How to click on the input element with value as Download Catalogues using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am trying to automate the downloading of an excel file. This is my first time using selenium and i don't normally code in Python so maybe a bit of a basic question.

I have got a login in and ticking a checkbox working, but the second to last step which is clicking a download button which seems to be a  . I have looked around stack overflow and google i can find similar problems but i can not find a solution that fixes my problem. I am normally using

```
.find_element_by_xpath
```

Which works for everything else but not the download button. I have added a wait to make sure page is fully loaded but it does not make it any easier.

```
#Downlod checked Catalogue
CatDownloadBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[1]')
CatDownloadBtn.click()
```

I have tired the xpath and full xpath neither worked.

I am getting the following error.

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element  is not clickable at point (213, 17). Other element would receive the
> click: [...](/Catalogues)

[image]

The Inspector -> Element as in code.

```
<div class="col-md-offset-0 col-md-10 downloadBtn">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Catalogues">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Attributes">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Enhanced Data">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello thanks for all your help and solutions really appreciate everyone's time. So i managed to solve this using the following.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
```

Then before CatDownloadBtn i use control + home to get to the top of the page.

```
#Go back to the top of the page
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)
```

So my full snippet would look like this.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#Go back to the top of the page
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('body').send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + Keys.HOME)

#Downlod checked Catalogue
CatDownloadBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[1]')
CatDownloadBtn.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

This normally happens because the element your trying to click is not clickable, there are multiple 'building blocks' to make a working element, this error normally occurs because your trying to click the wrong 'block'.

A way to combat this is to try clicking different elements, either going up a level or further down, I think in your case it's supposed to be further up since 'input' normally isn't clickable.

Since I don't know what the website is, I can't give specifics

Answer (score 0):

Indicates that a click could not be properly executed because the target element was obscured in some way.

Try JS script sample like below

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='button']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Also if does not work try with waits

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element));

Answer (score 0):

**ElementClickInterceptedException** is an exception which occurs when some other element comes in front of another or something which would prevent a real human click (e.g. when you need to scroll down). There are few solutions you can try.

## Solution 1 (Javascript executer):

```
CatDownloadBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/form/div[2]/input[1]')
driver.execute_script('arguments[0].click()', CatDownloadBtn) # Performs a Javascript click
```

## Solution 2 (Make sure element does not get intercepted):

You can check if there is a need to scroll down before clicking.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)") # Y is the height
```

## Extra:

Button can be selected by **value** using:

```
CatDownloadBtn = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Download Catalogues"]')
```

Comment: Hi Ali Sajjad, thanks for your help. I think it due to having to scroll down the page to check the checkbox. So i think i might need to get the view back to the top of the website.

Comment: @PhilWilky If you don't want to scroll or don't really need to make selenium script human like, then using the javascript must solve the problem :-) Did you try that?

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` element with text as **Download Catalogues** you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and `submit()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.downloadBtn>input[value='Download Catalogues']"))).submit()
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `click()`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'downloadBtn')]/input[@value='Download Catalogues']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB,
Thanks for helping out.

Using CSS_SELECTOR and submit():
i get 
selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: arguments[0].submit is not a function

Using XPATH and click():
selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Download Catalogues"> is not clickable at point (213, 17). Other element would receive the 
click: <a href="/Catalogues">...</a>

Am i doing something wrong?

Comment: @PhilWilky How about the _xpath_?